# Third Non-Zero Vector T (linear algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $v = \begin{bmatrix} 2& 1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $w = \begin{bmatrix} 1& 3\end{bmatrix}$. I calculated that they are independent. The span is $(2x+y, x + 3y)$. Correct me if I'm wrong. Does there exist a nonzero vector $t = \begin{bmatrix}t_1& t_2\end{bmatrix}$ that is simultaneously perpendicular to both $v$ and $w$? If so, find t.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

Such a vector $w=\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$ would satisfy the system of linear equations
$$\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\1&3\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Two vectors in the 2d plane are linearly independent unless they are parallel (one is a scalar multiple of the other one).

The span is correct, and nevertheless, it equals to the set of all planar vectors $\Bbb R^2$.

**Hint:** Draw and then find using vector algebra the set of vectors that are perpendicular to $v$. (Note that $v$ is the vector that goes $2$ units to the right and $1$ upwards.) Do the same for $w$.
Are there any nonzero vector in common?

Comment: Can I put the answer? (I figured it out, they don't have t.)

Comment: Sure. $\,\!\,\!\,\,$